# Fill second select with onchange of first one on MVC3 without javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu

i have a project on MVC3 and Razor.
I'm doing on my project everything without javascript first and then in the future when everything works without JS, then i will add the JS functionallity.
The thing is that i have a razor page, that i fill from the Model a select and what i need is that when the select option changes, then another select must be filled.
My idea is that in the Model i have a collection of the object that needs the second select to get filledm, and when the onchange event of the first select is triggered, i call a method on the controller that fills the list on the model and in the view side, i fill the second select with a foreach over the list.
My question is.. how do i fire the onchange event on a ? 
Notice that i'm not using Html.DropDownList or something like that.. but if it´s necessary, i will.

Thanks and i hope you can hellp me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `select` `onchange` event requires Javascript. To handle when Javascript is disabled you usually add something like an "Update" `submit button` within `<noscript>` tags to update the selection using a server post. The `<noscript>` tags will only show when Javacript is disabled.

Comment: I would opt for not using the `noscript` tag. It's better to add the button as you mention and remove it (display: none) with javascript. Then if javascript is not enabled the button will not be removed. This is a more empirical test: either the botton is there or it will be removed by the functionality you are testing for.

Comment: +1 Great idea - however OP, remember that going with this approach means you will be ballooning the size of your controllers.

Comment: @Bazzz, either way is fine but I agree with you that generally showing the non-Javascript version and using Javascript to remove this is usually the way to go. I add all events in this way rather than using onchange etc within elements. Seperates your Javascript from your HTML that way :o)

Comment: Tejs, what are you meaning with "ballooning the size of your controllers"?

Comment: @Tejs, this only makes your View bigger; not the Controller. Of course creating AJAX postbacks and stuff will but not just what I've mentioned for submitting the select change without JS.

Comment: You're going to have to add a bunch of Action Methods to deal with the post backs, and then have a bunch of views designed specifically to handle those situations. Making sure that they dont get called out of order, or that they can handle out of order (if possible with your page) would be time consuming. IE if you can click the drop down button, or click other buttons to do partial updates, do each view handle that situation?